# "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services" when app is installed on real device

Tags: android, google-play-services

When I install my app on Android devices running older versions (for example 4.4.4), I get this message. All the other posts I can see relating to this message seem to be when running on the emulator and related to Google Maps API. I am using Google Play Service 7.0.0.

Comment: when you use play services 7.0.0 library, the device has to have at least v7.0.0 play services installed.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: So should I use an older SDK? is there a better way to handle this than asking my users to update their Google Play Services?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This android developer's blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html#uds-search-results) describes what's new in the version 7.0 of Google Play services.

If you don't need those you're good to go with version 6.5 which already uses new `GoogleApiClient` class and provides granular dependency modules (best described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html).

In one of my projects i use this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

It's the whole package and I'll pick only the modules I need before deployment. Works fine against target API 22.

The farthest version I'd go with would be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

This one introduced the unified `GoogleApiClient` approach used today.

> So should I use an older SDK?

Absolutely not, this is not an SDK related problem. Keep everything (build tools, compile SDK, target SDK) to 22.

> is there a better way to handle this than asking my users to update their Google Play Services?

See above, use older version of the library with your project.

Comment: Thanks! what I meant by older SDK was for play-services. I am using play services to support push notifications through GCM. I don't want to have the latest version of play-services in my app and have users that are lazy to upgrade not get notifications. Based on your answer, it seems like the best thing to do is to use the older version (6.1.71 or whatever supports GCM). Is there a site which lists Android version and the play-service version bundled in?

Comment: [GCM client doc](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) seems to mention `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"`, so does that mean I can get away with using play-services 3.1?

Comment: Only if you want to use old, deprecated and most importantly undocumented API (Google deletes old documentation for Play services API). Let's assume that Play services app in the phone is always up-to-date. If it's not, the user either deactivated it or can't update it because there's not enough space so he's not able to install anything.

Comment: Or the latest version was not released for that device yet. You should be just fine with version 6.1. It has new APIs and considering it was released 6 months ago, everyone should have it.

Answer (score 2):

> "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services" when app is installed on real device

You get this message on your phone because your device has low version of google play service compared to the one used in the app.

Updating it, will work properly

Comment: But my app crashes upon showing this message on the emulator.

Comment: You didn't explain how to update it. I have same problem on a fresh installation of the latest version of Android Studio and all of the dependencies.